# android facebook SDK what Social Dialogs are available for android

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

i'm trying to use the Facebook SDK and Facebook Object in order to use facebook's dialogs in my android application.

for now i've found out that the "feed" dialog is working in this display type, but "send" and "friends" doesn't..

can some one please provide some kind of list of the Facebook Dialogs which are available for android platform ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the official documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/).

The dialog has three parameters, the action param decides the type of the dialog.

Quote:

> action - The type of dialog to call. Currently supported methods are
>   feed, apprequests and oauth.